# Resources in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating ASP.NET 5 application in VS2015. I added a resource file, but I cant use it in other projects, because its *.Designer.cs contains class with *internal* modifier and I can't change *Access Modifier* option in editor because it's disabled. I can manually replace *internal* with *public* but obviously it will be overriden.

I cant find any other workaround or solution. Is it bug? Or not yet finished feature? Or I'm doing something wrong? It worked in previous versions of VS.